# what version of java is compatible sonar-maven-plugin

Tags: sonarqube, maven-3, sonarqube-scan, sonar-maven-plugin

We are working on a existing project which should be compiled only in Java 6 version.We have sonar 4.5.7 to analyze the code quality.Now my question is the sonar-maven-plugin compatibility version which should work with Java 6. 
I have tried sonar-maven-plugin ver 2.4 and this is not working with Java6. So can someone tell me what is the comparability matrix of sonar-maven-plugin wrt. to java version. I must tell you that i have maven 3 in my system.

I have tried older version of sonar-maven-plugin 2.0 and they are not generating jacaco reports which i need to prepare the sonar dashboard for condition coverage.

Comment: why not try the latest?

Comment: exiting project so can't change the stack nor the sonar version as it has many compatible plugins which do not work on latest version of sonar

Answer (score 3):

There is not a matrix.

The version you're on is compatible with Java 7. That means you can still compile with Java 6 (or 5 or heaven forfend 4), but the analysis must be run with Java 7.

For SonarQube 5.6+ the requirement is Java 8. So again, compile with what you want, but analyze with Java 8.

Comment: Can i run the code analysis with java 6 (instead of java 7) for sonarqube version 4.5.7 , haven't tried it yet but if yes then what can be the sonar-maven-plugin